# Error using Connections in c++ defined QML Type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

when using `Connections` on a c++ defined QML Type, I get the following error:
*Cannot assign to non-existent default property*.

Following code produces the error:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQml 2.15
import myextension 1.0

Window {
    id:root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Custom
    {
        Connections{
            //target:root
            //function onWidthChanged(){console.debug("received")}
        }
    }
}
```

**customcppclass.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMCPPCL_H
#define CUSTOMCPPCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
class Message : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

};
#endif // CUSTOMCPPCLASS_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "customcppclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<Message>("myextension", 1, 0, "Custom");

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Is there a different way to receive the changed signals of properties in a qml extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with Connections objects, or your custom C++ class. You will get the same error if you do this:

```
    QtObject {
        Item { }
    }
```

Everything in a QML object has to be stored in a property, including child objects. But it doesn't usually look like a property because they use a [default property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) that automatically moves objects into the list of children.

```
    Item {
        QtObject { }
    }
```

is effectively the same as:

```
    Item {
        data: QtObject {}
    }
```

Where `data` is the name of the default property that `Item` uses to hold its child objects.

The problem with your code is that your object is a simple QObject and has no default property and no built-in method for managing children. The easy way to solve your problem is by creating your Connections object as its own property.

```
Custom {
    property Connections myConnections: Connections {
        target: root
        function onWidthChanged() { console.debug("received") }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to make it more like the way `Item` manages its children, then you would have to modify your C++ class to maintain a list and add a default property. That's most likely overkill for your needs though.

**UPDATE:**

The "overkill" solution would look something like this (This is just extracted from QQuickItem source code):

```
class Message: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QObject> data READ data)
    Q_CLASSINFO("DefaultProperty", "data")

public:
    QQmlListProperty<QObject> data();
    static void data_append(QQmlListProperty<QObject> *, QObject *);
    static int data_count(QQmlListProperty<QObject> *);
    static QObject *data_at(QQmlListProperty<QObject> *, int);
    static void data_clear(QQmlListProperty<QObject> *);
};
```

You can read up on [QQmlListProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html) or read the [QQuickItem](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp) source to figure out the implementation of those functions.

Comment: I am also interested in the "overkill" solution

Comment: See my edit for the overkill. I don't have time to fully flesh it out, but you can read the Qt source to see how they do it.